# Can I use a curl php object to multi request?

Tags: php, curl, request

I guys I have a doubt. I have to consume an API but I don't want to make several request and create several curl php objects.
I would like just change the url ,set it, and make an exec to get the result.

My code just change one parameter for the curl. I cant find a apropiate concept and example maybe you can help me I will be greatful guys.

I hope my question wont be so stupid for you. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. cURL Allows the processing of multiple cURL handles asynchronously. Look at this documentation [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Comment: But curl_multi_init is to make request from other domains API isn't it ?. In my case I just want to change one param is the same.  is there other way to do it ?